# Can I cancel out the gravitational force when calculating the gravitational constant?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, gravity, newtonian-gravity

Basically, this is what i’m doing:

$$F = m_1a$$

$$F = \frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$$

where:

$F$: gravitational force

$m_1$: mass of the earth

$m_2$: mass of object dropped

$a$: gravitational acceleration (9.81)

$r$: distance of the object from the Earth's centre

$G$: gravitational constant

So if I make them equal each other,

$$m_1a = \frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$$

$$r^2 = \frac{Gm_1m_2} {m_1a}$$

$$r^2 =\frac{Gm_2} {a}$$

So then i can draw a graph of $r^2$ against $\frac{m_2}{a}$, making $G$ the slope and my life easier.

Does the physics check out?

My teacher tells me I have to $m_1$ has to be the mass of the object. This will then cancel out to leave the mass of the Earth in the equation.

$$r^2 =\frac{Gm_2} {a}$$

My problem with this is that since $G$ is the gravitation constant and $a$ is the gravitational acceleration (also a constant, 9.81) and I can't change the mass of the Earth, this will produce a straight line and I won't be able to produce a graph to measure G through the slope. So the question becomes whether the physics would work if I cancel out the mass of the Earth.

Comment: Is this an experimental analysis or a derivation? Where will you get your values to "draw a graph?"

Comment: Also, you should learn to use Mathjax. Here is a tutorial/reference: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: "gravitational acceleratation" of what? You have the earth accelerating. How would you measure that?

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Commenters, please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $F=m_1a$ is using the mass of the earth to calculate the gravitational force on a falling object, so the acceleration term is referring to the acceleration of the earth towards that falling object.  While mathematically correct, how do you intend to measure the acceleration of the earth to a degree of precision that will result in an answer that is anywhere close to the correct answer?

Comment: I thought I'd use 9.81?

Comment: @Meera And that would be incorrect.

Comment: @meera, the acceleration of $m_2$ is 9.81 $m/s^2$.  Due to conservation of momentum, the acceleration of the earth is smaller by the ratio of $m_2/m_1$, where $m_1$ is approxomately $6 x 10^{24}$ kg.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is a recognised technique to calculate a constant by choosing axes such that you have a straight line graph.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is "Does the physics check out? "  OP hasn't carefully defined the "gravitational acceleration" or the "height", so the question is not clear enough to answer.

Comment: "Yes" qualifies as a valid answer to the question "Does the physics check out?"